# How to center elements on navbar | SCSS with Astro

Tags: html, css, sass, astrojs

My SCSS isn't working correctly. It should center the links of the navbar component I'm trying to make and not the logo. The css doesn't center them both.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h19l.png)

The following code is my css (SCSS):

```scss
.navbar {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.name {
  font-family: "Marcellus", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  .item {
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }

  .link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  }
}
```

The following is my html code (Astro):

```html
---
import './Navbar.scss'

export interface Props {
  links: {
    title: string;
    href: string;
  }[]
}

const { links } = Astro.props;
---

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="name">
    <a class="text-gradient" href="/">MysticalLira</a>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <ul class="links">
      {links.map(link => (
        <li class="item">
          <a class="link" href={link.href}>{link.title}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't you be missing a closing "}" in your code?

.links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

Comment: @DaniloFagundes No - these are SCSS nested classes

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox automatically makes things as small as possible to fit the content. So you need to tell your `.center` to grow to fill the remaining space in the `.navbar` box.

```scss
.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Be sure to use the inspector in your browser's dev tools to visualize the flexbox and see what it's doing.

Comment: Thx! They still don't look like they are fully in the center tho, but I can experiment with the `flex-grow`.

Comment: You won't be able to properly center them because the logo is offsetting the navbar. Any attempts to hack around that will probably result in the navbar crashing into, or overlapping the logo.

Comment: Yeah, i probably need to have them in the same class.